# hdfs - get folder/file creation timestamp

Tags: bash, hdfs

I am trying to retrieve the creation timestamp for a specific folder stored in hdfs, but I did not find a command that can get this information.

Apparently, as the -help command states out, the `-stat` command can only retrieve the modification date using the `%y` option:

```
bash$ hdfs dfs -help stat
-stat [format] <path> ... :
  Print statistics about the file/directory at <path> in the specified format.
  Format accepts filesize in blocks (%b), group name of owner(%g), filename (%n),
  block size (%o), replication (%r), user name of owner(%u), modification date
  (%y, %Y)
```

Is there some way to get the creation date?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS stores only the modified time and access time of the files as per the HDFS inode code in GitHub - [HERE](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/INodeAttributes.java#L61-L65).

The modified time for files is the time when the file was last closed (such as when originally written and closed, or when reopened for append and closed).

During most of the time the modified time does not change for most files we place on HDFS unless they undergo any modifications as stated above. Hence, the modified can be referred as an acceptable creation time most of the time (NOT ALWAYS).